# Does there exist a primitive recursive algorithm whose execution result can be verified non-recursively?

Tags: algorithms

Does there exist a primitive recursive algorithm whose execution result on arbitrary input can be verified without re-executing the algorithm itself, or with a computational complexity that is lower than the recursive algorithm?

Comment: Would a very bad algorithm for an easy problem be an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Isn't the typical NP-complete problem an instance of this? You can solve it in exponential time, say, but verify it in polynomial time.